# DataFormat.Error: We couldn't convert to Number. Details: Iodine Containing

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I'm trying to merge queries as new in Power BI using two tables i.e ChartEvents & D_Items from mimic CSV data files. When I do so it's throwing below error. What are the reasons for this / how can I solve this
[image]

Comment: theres something wrong with your source queries. You have to backtrack and find which one, and in what line

Answer (score 0):

One of your `'D_Items'[itemid]` is a *string* `"Iodine Containing"` instead of a *numerical* item id you'd expect, causing `Table.NestedJoin` to error while trying to convert that string value to a number.